# iOS/Android Deep Linking from Mail/Website

Tags: android, ios, app-store, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

My use case is as follows:

I send an email to a user of mine with a link to the iOS/Android apps of us.

Is there a possibility to enhance the links to these apps with an argument like `userId=123` which then gets passed to the app on startup.

Secondly can I pass this parameter even through the respective App Stores so that on on first launch after installation this argument is available to me? This would be the case if my user has not yet installed the app

Comment: Usually this is how it works . you register a URI for deep link and u can add parameter as query params like a GET URL like `http://www.example.com/user?userId=123` . it will be valid URL then u can Parse it inside the app and get the value of param .

Comment: I tried to find some documentation which outlines the process from Apple resp. Google and was not successful. Do you have any pointers?